# How to create horizontal scrollable container contains multiple rows

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I was trying to make a datagrid in which the **sticky navbar can be scrolled horizontally alongside the contents** below it. However the behavior changes in two scenes.

- When the outermost box is too narrow, the main region can be scrolled horizontally, however, the width of `nav` and `rows` are constrained to the parent box's width, causing the undesired behavior of
  background-color.

  - This can be solved by setting the width of both `nav` and `rows` to `fit-content`
- When the outermost box is too wide since the width has been set to `fit-content`, all rows are shrunk onto the left side instead of filling the whole row.

  - This can be solved by setting the width of both `nav` and `rows` to `100%`

So what should I do to make them behave correctly in both circumstances.

Other solutions I tried:

- Use `flex-row` with `warp`, however, the navbar and the rows would **be at the same row**, when the contents' width is too small.
- Use `inline-block` in `nav` and `inline-flex` in `rows`, the behavior is the same as the above one.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
        .grid {
            height: 60px;
            width: 200px;
            overflow: auto;
        }
        .subgrid {

        }
        .nav {
            position: sticky;
            top: 0;
            background: #da1039;
        }
        .rows {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            flex-wrap: nowrap;
            background: #00b89c;
        }
        .row {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            flex-wrap: nowrap;
            justify-content: space-evenly;
        }
        .rowitem {
            border: 1px solid;
            min-width: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="subgrid">
        <div class="nav">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="rowitem">HHH</div>
                <div class="rowitem">HHH</div>
                <div class="rowitem">HHH</div>
                <div class="rowitem">HHH</div>
                <div class="rowitem">HHH</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rows">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
        .grid {
            height: 60px;
            width: 50px;
            overflow: auto;
        }
        .subgrid {

        }
        .nav {
            position: sticky;
            top: 0;
            background: #da1039;
        }
        .rows {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            flex-wrap: nowrap;
            background: #00b89c;
        }
        .row {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            flex-wrap: nowrap;
            justify-content: space-evenly;
        }
        .rowitem {
            border: 1px solid;
            min-width: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="subgrid">
        <div class="nav">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="rowitem">HHH</div>
                <div class="rowitem">HHH</div>
                <div class="rowitem">HHH</div>
                <div class="rowitem">HHH</div>
                <div class="rowitem">HHH</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rows">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually combine both.

eg:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
        .grid-1 {
            height: 60px;
            width: 200px;
            overflow: auto;
        }

        .grid-2 {
            height: 60px;
            width: 900px;
            overflow: auto;
        }
        /* here */
        .nav {
            min-width: fit-content;
            max-width: 100%;
            position: sticky;
            top: 0;
            background: #da1039;
        }
        .rows {
            min-width: fit-content;
            max-width: 100%;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            flex-wrap: nowrap;
            background: #00b89c;
        }
        .row {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            flex-wrap: nowrap;
            justify-content: space-evenly;
        }
        .rowitem {
            border: 1px solid;
            min-width: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="grid-1">
        <div class="nav">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="rowitem">HHH</div>
                <div class="rowitem">HHH</div>
                <div class="rowitem">HHH</div>
                <div class="rowitem">HHH</div>
                <div class="rowitem">HHH</div>
                <div class="rowitem">HHH</div>
                <div class="rowitem">HHH</div>
                <div class="rowitem">HHH</div>
                <div class="rowitem">HHH</div>
                <div class="rowitem">HHH</div>
                <div class="rowitem">HHH</div>
                <div class="rowitem">HHH</div>
                <div class="rowitem">HHH</div>
                <div class="rowitem">HHH</div>
                <div class="rowitem">HHH</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rows">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="height: 20px"></div>
    <div class="grid-2">
        <div class="nav">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="rowitem">HHH</div>
                <div class="rowitem">HHH</div>
                <div class="rowitem">HHH</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rows">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
                <div class="rowitem">AAA</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's like magic, thanks. By the way, I saw the mdn said min-width override max-width, so what's the meaning of max-width.

Comment: And if the `sub-grid` div is nessesary?

Comment: `max-width` is the maximum width that the block can take.

Comment: I mean if it actually works under the existence of min-width.

Comment: yes,  `min-width` overrides `max-width` just means: if there is conflict between two - `min-width` takes priority. as for the `subgrid`: I donno. I thought you intend it for other purpose. I just put it there so, it will be usefull if you are copy-pasting. It was in your original code sample.

Comment: to visualise the overriding, see the example 1. the `fit-content` value is larger than `max-width` (ie: 100%) so it overrode `max-width` there. see <https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/m/max-width/#:~:text=The%20max%2Dwidth%20property%20in,after%20width%20in%20your%20declaration.> if you need more info

Comment: also removed subgrid

Comment: by the way. you can use `width=100%` instead of `max-width=100%` in your example if it confuses you. It also have the same effect in this context. I thought `max-width` would make more sense in literal terms.